# Why when I run `head(df$date_time_hour)` I don't get the proper format that I know that the variable has (`%Y-%m-%d %H`)

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a data frame `df` with a column called `datetime` that summarises date and time. This column is in POSIXct format ("%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S). I created a new variable called `Date_time_hour` from this in which I only want the hour time (format "%Y:%m:%d %H"). My doubt is that when I run `head(df$date_time_hour)`, I get the date but not the time in the console. Why is this? Am I doing something wrong?

The curious thing is that I don't get the commented problem with the below example.

The example:

```
df1<-data.frame(DateTime=c("2016-08-01 12:04:07","2016-08-01 12:06:07","2016-08-01 13:12:12","2016-08-01 14:04:07","2016-08-01 15:01:45","2016-08-01 15:34:07","2016-08-01 16:25:16","2016-08-01 16:29:16","2016-08-01 16:33:16","2016-08-01 16:54:16","2016-08-01 16:58:16","2016-08-01 17:13:16","2016-08-01 17:21:16","2016-08-01 17:23:42","2016-08-01 17:27:16","2016-08-01 17:28:16","2016-08-01 17:29:28","2016-08-01 17:42:08"),Var1=c( "V6", "V7", "V6", "V6", "V7", "V7", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V9", "V7", "V4" ),Var3=c(16 , 17, 19, 16, 17, 16, 17, 16, 16, 19, 17, 16, 16, 17, 17, 19, 16, 17))
df1$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df1$DateTime, format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz= "UTC")
df1$Date_time_hour<- strptime(df1$DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H",tz= "UTC")
df1$Date_time_hour<- as.POSIXct(df1$Date_time_hour, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

df1
              DateTime Var1 Var3      Date_time_hour
1  2016-08-01 12:04:07   V6   16 2016-08-01 12:00:00
2  2016-08-01 12:06:07   V7   17 2016-08-01 12:00:00
3  2016-08-01 13:12:12   V6   19 2016-08-01 13:00:00
4  2016-08-01 14:04:07   V6   16 2016-08-01 14:00:00
5  2016-08-01 15:01:45   V7   17 2016-08-01 15:00:00
6  2016-08-01 15:34:07   V7   16 2016-08-01 15:00:00
7  2016-08-01 16:25:16   V6   17 2016-08-01 16:00:00
8  2016-08-01 16:29:16   V6   16 2016-08-01 16:00:00
9  2016-08-01 16:33:16   V6   16 2016-08-01 16:00:00
10 2016-08-01 16:54:16   V7   19 2016-08-01 16:00:00
11 2016-08-01 16:58:16   V7   17 2016-08-01 16:00:00
12 2016-08-01 17:13:16   V7   16 2016-08-01 17:00:00
13 2016-08-01 17:21:16   V6   16 2016-08-01 17:00:00
14 2016-08-01 17:23:42   V6   17 2016-08-01 17:00:00
15 2016-08-01 17:27:16   V6   17 2016-08-01 17:00:00
16 2016-08-01 17:28:16   V9   19 2016-08-01 17:00:00
17 2016-08-01 17:29:28   V7   16 2016-08-01 17:00:00
18 2016-08-01 17:42:08   V4   17 2016-08-01 17:00:00
```

For the above example, when I do `head(df1$Date_time_hour)`, I get this:

```
> head(df1$Date_time_hour)
[1] "2016-08-01 12:00:00 UTC" "2016-08-01 12:00:00 UTC" "2016-08-01 13:00:00 UTC" "2016-08-01 14:00:00 UTC" "2016-08-01 15:00:00 UTC"
[6] "2016-08-01 15:00:00 UTC"
```

But with my own data data frame `Owndata`, when I do `head(Owndata$Date_time_hour)`, I get this:

```
> head(Owndata$Date_time_hour)
[1] "2016-07-20 UTC" "2016-07-20 UTC" "2016-07-20 UTC" "2016-07-20 UTC" "2016-07-20 UTC" "2016-07-20 UTC"
```

However, I know that the format of `Date_time_hour` in my own data is correct since:

```
> str(Owndata$Date_time_hour)
 POSIXct[1:2841756], format: "2016-07-20 00:00:00" "2016-07-20 00:00:00" "2016-07-20 00:00:00" "2016-07-20 00:00:00" "2016-07-20 00:00:00" "2016-07-20 00:00:00"
```

Just another clue:

```
> dput(head(Owndata))
structure(list(Date_time_hour = structure(c(1468972800, 1468972800, 
1468972800, 1468972800, 1468972800, 1468972800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date = structure(c(17002, 17002, 17002, 
17002, 17002, 17002), class = "Date"), LN = c(0.407596172920513, 
0.407596172920513, 0.407596172920513, 0.407596172920513, 0.407596172920513, 
0.407596172920513)), .Names = c("Date_time_hour", "Date", "LN"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

My `Owndata` data frame has 2841756 rows. I don't know if that's the reason... Although it would strange...

Comment: Can you please provide a small code snippet with __dput(head(your_own_data))__ ? That would be helpful for further investigations.

Comment: Done! I modified the name of my data frame to do it more understandable for people who read the post...

Comment: strangely `str(Owndata $Date_time_hour)` shows only `POSIXct[1:6], format: "2016-07-20" "2016-07-20" "2016-07-20" "2016-07-20" "2016-07-20" "2016-07-20"` no time component at all. I have a feeling some enteries in your data is still different than `Owndata` you have shared or `df1`.

Comment: It is strange. I created different columns related to datetime. All of them come from the variable `Datetime`. I created a variable called `Date_time_hour` that consider neither minutes nor seconds and a variable called `Round_datetime` that rounds `Datetime` to Hours. When I run `head(Owndata$Datetime)`, I get the proper format but when I run either `head(Owndata$Date_time_hour)` or `head(Owndata$Round_datetime)`, I get `"2016-07-20 UTC"`. I think the problem could be the way I get those new variables? But it is strange because it is no reproducible using other data.

Comment: Note: otherwise, if I run `str(Owndata$Date_time_hour)` or `str(Owndata$Date_time_hour)`, I get this: `POSIXct[1:2666802], format: "2016-07-20 00:00:00"`. Is it normal that `UTC` doesn't appear with the latter command? What worries me is that the format were incorrect, but I guess it is not the case....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that because every entry in `df$Date_time_hour` has time set to `0:00`, the display is compacted to a date without time.

Adding one hour to each entry, the time will be displayed. Maybe you are subsetting the data, where time is set to `0:00` only, which explains this behavior.

```
require(lubridate)

require(lubridate)

df <- structure(list(Date_time_hour = structure(c(1468972800, 1468972800, 1468972800, 1468972800, 1468972800, 1468972800), 
                                                class = c("POSIXct",  "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                     Date = structure(c(17002, 17002, 17002,  17002, 17002, 17002), class = "Date")))

df$Date_time_hour + hours(1)
```

gives:

```
[1] "2016-07-20 01:00:00 UTC" "2016-07-20 01:00:00 UTC" "2016-07-20 01:00:00 UTC" "2016-07-20 01:00:00 UTC" "2016-07-20 01:00:00 UTC"
[6] "2016-07-20 01:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: You're right!! The point is that if the time is `00:00:00`, the display of `head(Owndata$Date_time_hour)` omits the time. For example, If I run `head(Owndata$Date_time_hour[32:40])`, the display is `[1] "2016-07-20 00:00:00 UTC" "2016-07-20 00:00:00 UTC" "2016-07-20 00:00:00 UTC" "2016-07-20 01:00:00 UTC" "2016-07-20 01:00:00 UTC"
[6] "2016-07-20 01:00:00 UTC"`, but if I run `head(Detections_all_7_clean$Date_time_hour[29:34])`, the display is `[1] "2016-07-20 UTC" "2016-07-20 UTC" "2016-07-20 UTC" "2016-07-20 UTC" "2016-07-20 UTC" "2016-07-20 UTC"`. There wasn't any problem with format then.